# How to programmatically create a list from an excel spreadsheet in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to create a list from an excel spreadsheet in SharePoint 2010. When a new Excel document is uploaded to a SharePoint library, a corresponding list will be created automatically. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two phases:

- Create an empty MS Access database and import your excel sheet into it (in MS access go to `External data -> Excel`, choose your file and follow the steps to import it.
- When you get the MS access table with the data from excel sheet, right click the table name in Tables section and go to `Export -> SharePoint list`. There you can specify the url of your SharePoint site and the name of the new list. Click Ok and wait until the list is created and the data is uploaded to SharePoint.

**EDIT:**
Since this needs to be done automatically (as stated in comments), this is the high overview of the things that needs to be done, with some useful links:

- Create [Event receiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg749858(v=office.14).aspx) for the library that the excel files will be uploaded to.
- In the ItemAdded Method write the code that will do the following:

  - Get the uploaded file
  - Parse the excel file using the [OpenXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx) library
  - [Create the list](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-sharepoint-list-programmatically1) in the SharePoint site, based on the columns taken from the excel file
  - Loop through all the rows in the excel file and insert the list item for each excel row.

Comment: Thank you Damjan for your response. However, my question is that 'Can this process be automated without any human intervention'?

Comment: This could be done automatically. You would need the code that would parse the excel file when it is uploaded, create the list and copy all the rows from the excel to the list. The code could be in event receiver if you have on-premise SharePoint or in some provider hosted add-in if you have SharePoint online.

Comment: I have SharePoint 2010 on-premise. Can you please share the sample code if you have any?